# Multiplication of a sparse matrix in compressed column storage with a column vector

Tags: c, opencl

I have to multiply a sparse matrix in compressed column storage with a column vector(I have to parallelize it in open cl).I searched all around the internet.Spent so many days but couldnt find anything.(I am allowed to search the internet as i have to convert it to parallel).But i was only able to find code for compressed row storage.

```
spmv_csr_serial(const int num_rows ,
                const int * ptr ,
                const int * indices ,
                const float * data ,
                const float * x,
                float * y)
{
    for(int row = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        float dot = 0;
        int row_start = ptr[row];
        int row_end = ptr[row+1];

        for (int jj = row_start; jj < row_end; jj++)
            dot += data[jj] * x[indices[jj]];

        y[row] += dot;
    }
}
```

The compressed column storage doesn't have a row ptr. So how do I multiply it with the vector? I just need the serial code and I would convert it to parallel myself.

Here is my OpenCL kernel for this project

```
enter code here
__kernel void mykernel(__global const int* val,__global const int* index,__global const int * ptr,__global const int* x,__global int* y) 
{ 
    int id=get_global_id(0); 
    int colstart=ptr[id]; 
    int colend=ptr[id+1]; 
    for(int j=colstart;j<colend;j++) 
    { 
        y[index[j]]=val[j]*x[index[j]]; 
    } 
}
```

this code returns garbage value in open cl kernel.
This was my serial code.

```
   spmv_csr_serial(const int num_rows ,
                const int * ptr ,
                const int * indices ,
                const float * data ,
                const float * x,
                float * y)
{
    for(int row = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        float dot = 0;
        int colstart = ptr[row];
        int colend = ptr[row+1];

      for(int j=colstart;j<colend;j++) 
    { 
        y[index[j]]=val[j]*x[index[j]]; 
    }

    }
}
```

Algorithm for dense matrix vector multiplication

```
For(int i=0;i<A.RowLength;i++) 
{
    For(int j=0;j<vector.length;j++) 
    { 
        Result[i]=Result[i]+A[i][j]*vector[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the algorithm for doing a matrix vector computation is as follows

```
y = 0
for i = 0 : Nr - 1
    for j = 0 : Nc - 1
        y[i] += M[i,j] * x[j]
```

#### Compressed-row storage:

Instead of doing an ordinary loop over all columns, we loop over the non-zeros entries
only:

```
y = 0
for i = 0 : Nr - 1
    for j = 0 : numElementsInRow(i) - 1
        y[i] += M[i, columnIndex(i,j)] * x[columnIndex(i,j)]
```

where `numElementsInRow(i)` returns the number of non-zeros in the `i`-th row and `columnIndex(i,j)` gives the `j`-th column index in the `i`-th row.

In your implementation
above, your `columnIndex(i,j)` mapping is done by the two arrays `ptr` and `indices`, i.e.
`columnIndex(i,j) == indices[ptr[i] + j]` and the number of elements is given by
`numElementsInRow(i) == ptr[i+1] - ptr[i]`.
There is no need for indexing the matrix, because you only store the **compressed** version of it.

#### Compressed-column storage:

Now change the order of the two loops and loop over the non-zeros in the rows:

```
y = 0
for j = 0 : Nc - 1
    for i = 0 : numElementsInColumn(j) - 1
        y[rowIndex(j,i)] += M[rowIndex(j,i), j] * x[j]
```

And the rest is analog to the CRS format.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write out an algorithm for dense matrix-vector multiplication.  If you don't know how to do this, look in any elementary linear algebra textbook, or ask your professor.
2. Your algorithm will iterate over both the rows and columns of the matrix; re-arrange the algorithm if necessary so that the inner loop is over the columns.
3. Modify the algorithm to use your dense storage scheme for accessing the matrix.

Comment: The algo you asked me to write will be For(int i=0;i<A.RowLength;i++) { For(int j=0;j<vector.length;j++) { Result[i]=Result[i]+A[i][j]*vector[j];}}

Comment: In compressed row storage we had row ptr like i wrote in the very first code but how do iterate with a  column ptr? seems impossible.too confusing

Answer (score 1):

CCS is similar to CRS, just transposed. You don't have a row pointer, but you have a similar column pointer. Thus, your sequential loop should be

```
for(int col=0; col<num_cols; col++){
  for(int j=ptr[col];j<ptr[col+1]; j++) { 
    y[indices[j]] += val[j]*x[col]; 
  }
}
```

Remember to zero the y vector before.

Which one do you think is faster? CCS or CRS?